# how to manage multiple libraries on the same linux system?

Tags: software-installation, libraries, shared-library

I have only one PC with Linux installed. However, I have multiple versions of the same lib. Because different software may depend on different versions of the same lib, I have to keep all of them on the system.

Do you have any good ideas to keep them working well?

Any references are welcome.

## [Update]

For example:

I have two version of g++, e.g. g++4.8 and g++5.2.

I want their related files stored in different paths like:
`/soft/g++/4.8/` and `/soft/g++/5.2`

When I use g++, I can easily change the version by a simple command.
I have found Software Environment Management http://modules.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Package managers like on Debian derivatives handle that out of the box: I routinely have several versions of some particular library installed. Different directories, version suffixes for .`so`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If your library defines its [soname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) correctly, you can have multiple versions installed without any difficulty. For example, I currently have three versions of `libreadline` installed:

```
$ ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Dec  4  2015 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.5 -> libreadline.so.5.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263352 Dec  4  2015 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.5.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Oct  4  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 296792 Oct  4  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Jan 24 16:17 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7 -> libreadline.so.7.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 309168 Jan 24 16:17 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7.0
```

This works because programs link to the soname, so anything built for version 5 links against `libreadline.so.5`, anything built for version 6 links against `libreadline.so.6` etc. The requirement on the library side is that all versions with the same soname must preserve their ABI: new versions can add features, but they can’t break existing features. Any breaking change implies a soname bump.

If all this is done correctly (on the library side), you shouldn’t ever need multiple versions of a library with the *same* soname: as long as you have the latest version, you’ll be able to run any software built against any version of the library with the same soname. Continuing the `libreadline` example, software built with version 5.1 of the library runs fine with version 5.2. (The inverse isn’t necessarily true; software using new features in 5.2 won’t run with 5.1.)

It might be worth looking into `libtool` (yeah, I know) if you’re not already using it: it has a reasonably usable [versioning scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libtool-versioning.html) which handles soname bumps.

Some libraries go to extraordinary lengths to minimise the need for soname bumps; the GNU C library is an example, it uses symbol versioning extensively to avoid breaking ABI while still introducing new features and backwards-incompatible changes (it just keeps the old versions around, *inside* the library).